# Safari 7 application cache does not work

Tags: caching, safari, html5-appcache

In Safari 7, the main html file with a manifest is loadable when offline, but none of the external resources are loaded, even if they're listed in the manifest file as cached. Safari's resource pane lists the files as in the application cache, but it will not load them. I've tried an extremely simple test, checked MIME type of the manifest file, renamed the manifest file, and tried other demos. Here's an example that works fine on Chrome, but on Safari it will not load the sticky image when offline: http://htmlfive.appspot.com/static/stickies.html

This is the same problem described in [AppCache misbehaving in Safari, firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655771/appcache-misbehaving-in-safari-firefox), but I think that question doesn't make the problem as clear, and I wanted to provide a question with a concrete demo. Is there a work-around, or does Safari 7 totally not support application cache beyond the primary html file? Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution. I asked the same question at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912919/how-to-get-app-cache-manifest-to-work-on-safari-7-0-3

Comment: No, I spent many hours, and it seems to just not work. What's strange is that so few people have noticed it! I reported the bug to Apple, but they closed it as a duplicate with no comment, and what's worse is I can't figure out how to view the bug it's a duplicate of. The bug that Apple is tracking on their bug reporter is 15370653 - I would love to know how to view that, since all I seem to be able to view are the bugs I've filed.

Comment: Did the exact same thing. Mine was also marked as "Duplicate" and I could not view the original. Well at least it got some attention, they are aware of the issue. It works on iPad, iPhone and Chrome thou.

Comment: I think this is a bug with Safari on the desktop (iOS works fine). It looks like Safari tries to download the manifest from the server when offline. Safari should be using loading it from cache. File a radar https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Mark and I both filed bugs. They were both marked as duplicates, and we can't view the bug they're duplicates of. I e-mailed them twice, no response. I called the developer phone number and they said there was nothing they could do or tell me. Michael, can you file a bug as well and reference this SO question? This is a serious problem that they appear to not be addressing. Safari 7 has a bunch of other problems, too. It's a disaster for developers, and if Apple's not responding, that's even worse.

P.S. it's correct to try to download the manifest, but it should load other files if it fails.

Comment: Received a response from Safari. They said they're working on a fix and will notify me when it's available. No timeline, but I'll answer this question when I see a fix.

Comment: At least they acknowledged it as a bug. I will be using chrome instead, until they got a fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML 5 Appcache works in safari/opera/chrome but not firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443311/html-5-appcache-works-in-safari-opera-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that issue says it does work on Safari but this issue is it *doesn't* work on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Clear Cache in Safari version 7 on Mac OSX

You have two options to clear the cache in Safari version 6:
Use the "Empty Caches" option
Select which items you want to clear by using the "Reset" option